# How do I open locked chests?

Tags: bravely-default

I've encountered two blue chests so far in the game and they both read "Locked" whenever I try to open them. I haven't found any chest keys or other such items, so how am I supposed to unlock these treasures and exploit their valuable goods?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will receive the key in Chapter 6. When you're back in Grand Ship, you'll see a glowing object on the ground - pick it up. It's the Treasure Chest Key, and will unlock all the blue chests. They tend to carry the best items in the game, so remember where you found them and pick 'em up.

Answer (score 0):

You get a key for them later on in the game. It ties into the story. Its on the grandship.
its only available in chapter 6.

Comment: Please add more detail to this answer as it is currently low quality. When un the story do you get this "key"? Does it go by a specific name? Can I look through a menu to see if I already have it?

Answer (score 0):

Unlock all 4 crystals twice when you gain control of grand ship. It will be start of chapter 6 and the key will be on the floor of ship in form of glowing object.